# Implementing a (small) full-text search in Ruby

Tags: ruby, search, natural-language-processing

I'm trying to implement a small full-text search in Ruby. I feel like I've laid down the foundation but I've encountered a blocker that has gotten me thinking that something with the design is incorrect.

The general concept is that a `Document` is the basic unit. Multiple `Documents` form a `Collection`. The `InvertedIndex` takes a collection to `build` the index, which is a just hash of stemmed tokens with their respective document `id`s, for example:

```
inverted_index = {
  "new" => [1, 4],         # These are document ids.
  "home" => [1, 2, 3, 4],  # The key is stemmed and some stop-words
  "sale" => [1, 2, 3, 4],  # are being removed.
  "top" => [1],
  "forecast" => [1],
  "rise" => [2, 4],
  "juli" => [2, 3, 4],
  "increas" => [3]
})
```

**document.rb**

```
module Rankrb
  class Document
    attr_accessor :id, :body, :rank

    def initialize(params={})
      @id = params.fetch :id, nil
      @body = params.fetch :body, ''
      @rank = params.fetch :rank, nil
    end

    def length
      tokens.join(' ').length
    end

    def include?(term)
      tokens.include? term_to_token(term)
    end

    def term_freq(term)
      tokens.count term_to_token(term)
    end

    def tokens
      Rankrb::Tokenizer.new(@body).tokenize
    end

    def uniq_tokens
      tokens.uniq
    end

    private
    def term_to_token(term)
      Rankrb::Tokenizer.new(term).tokenize.shift
    end
  end
end
```

**tokenizer.rb**

```
module Rankrb
  # The same tokenizer should be used for document
  # tokenization and query tokenization to ensure that
  # the same terms are being searched and returned.
  class Tokenizer
    attr_accessor :str
    attr_reader :tokens

    def initialize(str='')
      @str = str
      @tokens = Array.new
      @stopwords = Rankrb.configuration.stopwords
      @lang = Rankrb.configuration.language
    end

    def tokenize
      regex = /[^\s\p{Alnum}\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Hangul}]/
      @tokens = @str.gsub(regex,'')
                    .downcase
                    .split
                    .delete_if {|token| @stopwords.include?(token)}
                    .map {|w| Lingua.stemmer(w, :language => @lang)}
      @tokens
    end
  end
end
```

**collection.rb**

```
module Rankrb
  class Collection
    attr_accessor :query, :docs

    def initialize(params={})
      @docs = params.fetch(:docs, [])
      @query = params.fetch(:query, nil)

      def @docs.<<(arg)
        self.push arg
      end
    end

    def remove_doc(doc)
      @docs.delete_if do |curr_doc|
        curr_doc == doc
      end
    end

    def containing_term(term)
      @docs.count {|doc| doc.include?(term)}
    end

    def avg_dl
      @docs.map(&:length).inject(:+) / total_docs
    end

    def total_docs
      @docs.size
    end

    def idf(term)
      numerator = total_docs - containing_term(term) + 0.5
      denominator = containing_term(term) + 0.5
      Math.log(numerator / denominator)
    end

    def bm25(params={:k => 1.2, :b => 0.75, :delta => 1.0})
      @k = params[:k]
      @b = params[:b]
      @delta = params[:delta]

      @docs.each do |doc|
        score = 0
        dl = doc.length
        query_terms = @query.split

        query_terms.each do |term|
          dtf = doc.term_freq(term)
          numerator = dtf * (@k + 1)
          denominator = dtf + @k * (1 - @b + @b * (doc.length / avg_dl))
          score += idf(term) * (numerator/denominator) + @delta
        end
        doc.rank = score
      end
      @docs.sort {|a, b| a.rank <=> b.rank}
    end
  end
end
```

**inverted_index.rb**

```
module Rankrb
  class InvertedIndex
    attr_accessor :collection, :iidx

    def initialize(params={})
      @collection = params.fetch(:collection, Rankrb::Collection.new)
      @index_file = 'db/index.json'
      @iidx = Hash.new
    end

    def build
      @collection.docs.each do |doc|
        # Make the inverted index hash
        doc.uniq_tokens.each do |token|
          if @iidx[token]
            @iidx[token] << doc.id
          else
            @iidx[token] = [doc.id]
          end
        end
      end
      # Now sort the document ids and return the inverted index!
      @iidx.each {|k, v| @iidx[k] = v.sort}
    end

    def remove_doc(doc)
      doc.tokens.each do |token|
        # Remove the document id
        @iidx[token].delete(doc.id)
        # Then remove the key from the hash if
        # there are no more docs.
        @iidx.delete(token) if @iidx[token].empty?
      end
      # Once all tokens have been removed,
      # remove the document from the collection.
      @collection.remove_doc(doc)
      @iidx
    end

    # Returns an array of document ids.
    def find(str)
      Rankrb::Tokenizer.new(str)
        .tokenize
        .map {|token| @iidx[token]}
        .compact
        .flatten
        .uniq
        .sort
    end

    # Define query_or and query_and methods.
    %w(and or).each do |op|
      define_method("query_#{op}") do |word_ary|
        doc_ids = Array.new
        word_ary.each {|word| doc_ids << find(word) }
        case op
        when 'and'
          symbol = :&  # Conjunctive query
        when 'or'
          symbol = :|  # Disjunctive query
        end
        doc_ids.inject(symbol)
      end
    end

    def commit!
      if File.exist?(@index_file)
        file = File.read @index_file
        # Merge the new tokens
        index = JSON.parse(file).merge(@iidx)
        File.open(@index_file, 'w+') { |f| f.write(index.to_json) }
      else
        # Create & write to file for the first time
        File.open(@index_file, 'w') { |f| f.write(@iidx) }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

You'd run it as follows:

```
d1 = Rankrb::Document.new body: "new home sales top forecasts", id: 1
d2 = Rankrb::Document.new body: "home sales rise in july", id: 2
d3 = Rankrb::Document.new body: "increase in home sales in july", id: 3
d4 = Rankrb::Document.new body: "july new home sales rise", id: 4
coll = Rankrb::Collection.new docs: [d1, d2, d3, d4]
index = Rankrb::InvertedIndex.new collection: coll
index.build # Inverted-index gets built and stored into @iidx

index.find('top sales') # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is where I'm a bit lost. The current process does the following:

1. The `find` method in `InvertedIndex` returns an array of doc ids.
2. The doc ids need to be found within `Collection` (which currently holds ALL documents)
3. These documents need to be ranked.
4. `Collection` needs to return only the list of `Document`s that were ranked back over to `find` to respond to the query.

**The questions:**

- Storing all `Document`s in memory within `Collection` is the first thing that seems wrong to me, as this will eat of tons of RAM. However, I need them there in order for `find` to do something with the array of document ids that it returns. I can't exactly remove the `Document`s from memory since, as you can see from this case, **the query matched tokens in all of them**. Is there a better way to handle this situation?
- In order to rank `Document`s, I need to iterate over the array returned by `find` (eg. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`). This means I'd need to iterate over all these documents and return a **new array of documents** to `find`, so the id and rank can be preserved and returned.

Am I wrong to think this is slightly unreasonable? Is this design incorrect?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't contain all of your code. I say this because, when I try to use it, (a) it gives me `NoMethodError`s for `configuration` and that stuff, and (b) there's no single file which also `require`s the rest, which is typical for a rather large library like this.

Comment: Also, where's `Lingua`? That's not in there as far as I can tell.

Comment: Isn't this question kind of off topic..?

Answer (score 2):

I gave a talk at RailsConf a few years back where I did a walk through of some fundamentally similar code. In my talk, I actually used JRuby and OpenNLP but you can achieve the same result in Ruby MRI using some of the other libraries I call out in my deck.

https://speakerdeck.com/brandonblack/natural-language-processing-in-ruby?slide=31

In my example, I'm doing a poor man's summary of a block of text by identifying and grabbing the top "most significant" sentences in the document. It's a different goal, but many of the basic ideas translate over to what you're trying to do.

For a basic text search, you need to build an index that returns the most relevant items based on a given search phrase. Once you've built that index, searching it is simple.

For each segment of searchable text:

1. [Tokenize](https://github.com/lfcipriani/punkt-segmenter) all the input blocks of text.
2. Filter out [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) that have low value. You can do this with a library or for simple demo purposes you can just use a simple regex or blacklist.
3. Use a [word stemmer](https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer) to identify the root word for each token in the text block.
4. In your database, store an association between the word stem, the document being searched and a weighting for how many times that word stem appears in the text.
5. In your search method, follow the same process (tokenize, filter, stem) processing the search phrase and then return the documents found in your index for those stem words in the search phrase sorted by weight descending.

In the database, a row in the search index might look something like this:

```
stem_word_id, document_id, weight
```

If you had a table full of those associations, you'd just need to index that table across all 3 columns with a weight descending direction. For best results, consider using a database that leverages in-memory mapping (ex. MongoDB) for this index (similar to keeping this index in cache).

I hope that helps draw a rough picture of the process.

That being said, there are many more nuances to full text search. This is a very very simplistic, mostly naïve approach and without an appropriate data backend it would not scale very much for you (your spot on about storing these in memory being a long term losing strategy). If you're considering this for a production system, I would recommend using a database with full text search or something like [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) which there are Ruby-based adapters for.